# Firefox deleted innerHTML of generated iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I'm using JavaScript to build an iframe and insert some content into it. In Chrome and Safari it works fine but in Firefox the iframe remains empty. When logging the contents of the iframe it displays the HTML only right after creating it, afterwards innerHTML is empty.

Here is the code I'm using and here is a relevant JSBin: https://jsbin.com/tapacequtu/edit?html,js,output

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

const label = document.createElement('div');
label.innerText = 'Hello world';

iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(label);
```

Why is the iframe in Firefox empty?

Comment: why are you creating elements on 2 separate contexts?

Comment: this is the minimal example of a bigger project. I'm using an iframe to avoid having external CSS rules from affecting it

Comment: i mean you should call `createElement` for the document that actually needs the element.

Comment: Dont you need to give the iframe a `src` to load? Guess not ... looking at @RobFox solution below.

Comment: src is not needed for an iframe as I'm providing the content manually

Comment: it doesn't matter where you call createElement, it doesn't hold any context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a very old bug in Firefox reported here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=297685

You have to use a `setTimeout` to "fix" it:

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

setTimeout(() => {
  const label = document.createElement('div');
  label.innerText = 'Hello world';

  iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(label);  
}, 0);
```

Comment: Amazing that a bug like that still lingers.

Comment: Was just about to post the `setTimeout` idea.,  I noticed for a fraction of a second you actually see the text.  So I was assuming what's happening is that Firefox is loading the default iFrame contents, that overwrites what you have done.